# location = "file.exe", show download size during download?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, download

I use the following javascript snippet to let the user download a file when he clicks a button:

```js
location = 'http://www.example.com/files/installer.exe'
```

The problem is that while it works, it doesn't show the file size while downloading (tested in Firefox on Windows).

**Is there a way to tell the browser the size of the executable, so the user sees a progress bar while downloading?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not from client-side JavaScript—the browser has no way to know the size of a remote resource if the server doesn't say.

You need a server-side fix: generate a valid `Content-Length` header. Web servers typically do it automatically. If yours doesn't, that possibly means you have a server-side script that sends the file but does not report its size.

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to problems on the server-side; it's not a JavaScript bug.

What headers do the `GET` request to example.com/files/installer.exe returns? Maybe `Content-Length` header is missing, and the user browsers can't know the file size in advance.